# Image Loading to a custom View

Tags: android, android-custom-view, image-loading

I have a `custom ImageView` which extents from `FrameLayout` how can I **load image** to that view from a `Url`.

Thanks.

Comment: use image loader and get bitmap , set bitmap to the custom imageview

Comment: Use this lib http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) Library

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  google()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
}

GlideApp.with(this).load("YOUR_URL").into(imageView);
```